# Is it possible to add constraints to the parameters of a record type in C#?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to express the following class as a record type in C#?

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(int a, int b)
    {
        if (a != 0 && b != 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("You may not set both A and B");

        A = a;
        B = b;
    }

    public int A { get; }

    public int B { get; }
}
```

For the avoidance of doubt - is it possible to do this in a way that preserves the semantics and conciseness of a record type that looks like:

```cs
public record class MyClass(int A, int B);
```

?

Comment: @Selvin there multiple options - [for example without dummy param](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eSVgn0#). Note that this still can be easily broken with inits - [repro](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BnsqC8)